# Redux - Providing reducer function for create store error

Tags: redux, reducers

In this document, it wants 3 arguments, the 1st being the reducer.

https://redux.js.org/api/createstore

I understand that there needs to be a function defined, but where would this be coming from? Am I defining it or is this something that is imported?

Right now, I'm getting an error that `rootReducer is not defined`.

I guess I'm not sure what to do as for this particular assignment, all I needed to do was return JSON data from a provided endpoint.

I've done without the use of Redux/Thunk, but the requirements ask for it, along with Jest.

What would I add to the first argument?

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';

import thunk       from 'redux-thunk';

const initialState = {};

const middleware = [thunk];

const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
applyMiddleware(...middleware),

window._REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_ ? 
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__() : f => f

));
```

Answer (score 1):

Please take the time to read through [the Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/).  Redux expects you to write ["reducer functions"](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers) that define [how the state is initialized](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state) and updated.

Specific to the question of store setup, see the [docs page on "Configuring Your Store"](https://redux.js.org/recipes/configuring-your-store).